# Лицензии в приложении на React Native

Tags: react-native, лицензирование

Я понимаю, что об этом нужно консультироваться с юристом, но пока хотя бы поверхностно хочу прояснить для себя ситуацию.

1. Я так понимаю, если приложение использует Open JDK (просто папка с jdk в системе и путь к ней в JAVA_HOME, чтобы приложение собиралось), это не значит, что необходимо публиковать его исходный код и делать его некоммерческим (включая невозможность взимать плату за использование и/или предоставление платных услуг). Так ли это ?
2. Лицензии каких сторонних библиотек нужно указывать в приложении и нужно ли ? Скажем, в некоторых приложениях вообще нет пункта о лицензиях. В других, написанных на том же react native, есть пункт с перечислением библиотек и ссылками на их github репозитории.
   Допустим, я легко и с радостью сделаю экран с лицензиями на используемые npm-пакеты. Но нужно ли включать лицензии на используемые этими пакетами зависимости или это забота авторов самих пакетов ? Что насчет нативных библиотек ? Например, я понятия не имею, какие там android support libraries или androidx или play services используются, они просто включены самим react native и нативными модулями. Разумеется, общую картину то я понимаю, но многое от меня скрыто, т.к. я не лезу в исходники каждой библиотеки и не перечитываю java файлы.
3. Экрана с лицензионной информацией вообще достаточно ? В лицензиях идет речь о включении в исходный код, но я на процесс сборки не влияю и не знаю, что там где включается, разве что минифицированный js файл в apk могу посмотреть.
4. А если я лишние лицензии включу ? Скажем, babel или tslint у меня будет включен в список. Или я наоборот babel должен включать ? Typescript ? Все полифиллы babel ? В коде ведь будет присутствовать часть кода, сгенерированного этими пакетами.

На данный момент я так понимаю, что можно сделать экран со списком прямых зависимостей из package.json, если они все mit/apache/bsd и ссылками на их репозитории и этого будет достаточно.

Я, возможно, выражаюсь несколько резко, но ситуация с обилием лицензий и отсутствием внятной структурированной информации мне очень не нравится. Например, facebook недавно выпустили hermes engine. Если я включу использование hermes в приложении, мне нужно будет указывать его и его лицензию в списке стороннего ПО ? Как я должен об этом узнать и узнать наверняка.